# How to get apk path on Android Studio while programmatically installing it on 4.2

Tags: android, apk, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I trying to install an apk on button click

I'm calling the apkInstall("netflix") like this then I have the apk files save under

res > old > netflix.apk

res > new > netflix.apk

```
public String apkInstall(String name){
 
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 18){
                Log.d("State", "initializing old");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File
                        ("/src/main/res/old/"+name+".apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.d("End", "End old");
            }else{
                Log.d("State", "initializing new");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File
                        ("src/main/res/new/"+name+".apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                Log.d("intent", String.valueOf(intent));
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.d("End", "End new");
            }
}
```

I'm getting these logs

```
2022-04-13 02:35:07.822 24733-24733/com.mtl.installer D/State: initializing new
2022-04-13 02:35:07.828 24733-24733/com.mtl.installer D/intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///src/main/res/new/netflix.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive }
```

and I can't reach the log "End" and I'm lost because there's no error

any ideas?

Comment: Resources are not files on the filesystem of the device. They are files on the filesystem of your developer machine. They are merely entries in your app's APK on the device.

Comment: Put them in the `res/raw` folder and use Android to get a reference (like CommonsWare says)

Comment: @Blundell still not working. I tried to move it to res/raw then used this "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/"+name; and still same as before

Comment: The app you are sending the URI too might not have permission to read your private resources. Perhaps copy them to the filesystem of the device first